# How to properly use python's asyncio for a basic 'chat' client?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

First off, I apologize if the title is misleading or not specific enough.

I am actually writing an AV control system, and I'm trying to "chat" with a specific AV switcher. The switcher sends a constant stream of data for every little thing that happens.  For example, if the user hits the menu button on the front panel, the switcher sends data over the wire mirroring the command sequence it executed internally: screen blank off (`b'Z 0 8 0\r\n'`), video freeze off (`b'Z 0 9 0\r\n'`), toggle show menu (`b'Z 0 0\r\n'`).  I can connect to the switcher and send and receive data synchronously using sockets, but clearly the switcher is sending asynchronously because you can catch it in the middle of rambling off a huge wall of data sometimes - like when it boots up - and that's where I'm... clueless.  I've been trying to figure out asyncio, but it's a little hard to wrap my head around.  I'd like to have a very basic "chat client" where I see everything the switcher sends as it arrives, and have a prompt where I can manually enter commands and see the results come back.  Then ideally I would parse each fragment of data to get a picture of what state the switcher is in so I can track that state.  I found a "chat" example [here](https://github.com/henry232323/Simple-Asyncio-Chat-Client/blob/master/client.py) and tried to create my own version:

```
import asyncio
ip_address = 'the ip address :)'
ip_port = 5000

class Client(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        print('Connection established to ' + ip_address)

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('method start: data_received')
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('method start: connection_lost')
        if exc is None:
            print('EOF received')
        else:
            print('Connection terminated')

    def send(self, data):
        print('method start: send')
        if data:
            self.transport.write(data.encode())

    async def get_commands(self, loop):
        print('method start: get_commands')
        while True:
            # get inputs forever on a separate thread
            cmd = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, "Command: ")

            # send never gets called
            self.send(cmd)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    client = Client(loop)
    print('Attempting a connection to ' + ip_address + ':' + str(ip_port))
    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: client,
        host=ip_address,
        port=ip_port
    )
    asyncio.ensure_future(client.get_commands(loop))

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run it, it tells me a connection was successfully established, my debug message 'method start: get_commands' prints, and I get that initial prompt.  However, as soon as I type a command and press enter, the program terminates with no additional output.  I've tried debugging it in pycharm's debugger but when I do that, I don't even get a prompt - it just says connection established, prints the debug message and terminates immediately.  I tried using Wireshark to sniff it out and I never see an actual payload transmitted, just a lot of SYNing and ACKing.

Soooo... I'm kinda lost.  I know I must not be using asyncio correctly.  I've never really written anything asynchronous before except AJAX and on top of that I am also still learning python as I'm sure you can tell.  What am I doing wrong?  Alternatively, if anyone can point me to a really great async-for-idiots guide that would be great too :)  I really want a thick tome to teach me everything so I can be a zen master.

Comment: Change `asyncio.ensure_future(client.get_commands(loop))` to `await client.get_commands(loop)`. Also, you don't need to send loop around, you can obtain it using `asyncio.get_running_loop()` at the point where you need it.

Comment: I got it to work (sorta) by just adding `await` to the front of `asyncio.ensure_future(...)`. 
 Didn't know that was required but I guess it makes sense?  It's creating a task... I still need a good source of info for beginners.  Now the only visual oddity is that `Command:` prints before `Data received: ...` and I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Another thing is that you almost certainly don't want to implement your own `Protocol` - look into the [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) layer and [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) in particular.

Comment: Creating a Future or Task only to await it is a waste. You can directly ``await client.get_commands(loop)``.

Comment: `await asyncio.ensure_future(foo())` is just a less efficient way to write `await foo()`. (It's sort of like creating a thread with the specified target and then `join()`ing it immediately.) You need to create a future precisely when you _don't_ want to immediately await it, but you want to keep it running in the background.

Comment: Thanks! I was in the process of experimenting and was typing that comment right before I saw yours.  Now I'm trying to figure out a way to properly order the outputs.

Comment: I accomplished that by adding asyncio.sleep(0.1) just in front of the call to `loop.run_in_executor`.  Thanks all!  Any good sources (books, etc) of information you can point me to will be most welcomed.